# query on 2 fields but 1 is a unique value

Tags: postgresql, query, postgresql-9.6

postgresql 9.6, windows 7

Here is an example of a database :

```
fld1 fld2
abc  D123
xyz  D123
abc  D789
```

how can I select rows with `fld1='abc'` **if/only for** fld2 value exists just **one time** in the database ?
In my example, I only want to select the third row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have extended a bit your sample data:

```
create table tbl (fld1 text, fld2 text);
insert into tbl values
('abc',  'D123'),
('xyz',  'D123'),
('abc',  'D125'),
('abc',  'D128'),
('def',  'D128'),
('abc',  'D789');
```

You can use EXIST in your WHERE clause with a dataset grouped by `fld2`:

```
select
    t1.*
from
    tbl t1
where
    fld1 = 'abc'
    and exists (select 1 
                from tbl t2 
                where t2.fld2 = t1.fld2 
                group by fld2 
                having count(*) = 1);
```

> ```
> fld1 | fld2
> :--- | :---
> abc  | D125
> abc  | D789
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=53977521cc06877747f60db1326702e6)*

Or you can use a CTE to get all `fld2` rows with a count of 1, and join it with all rows where `fld1 = 'abc'`:

```
with count1 as
(
    select   fld2
    from     tbl
    group by fld2
    having   count(*) = 1
)
select
    t1.*
from
    tbl t1
join
    count1
    on t1.fld2 = count1.fld2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0197bf4463f9508cdd000232e28ae8ce)*

Comment: I like the second query, it talks to me more than the first. Thx

Comment: I'm glad to help.